# populate CheckBoxList from query using FindByValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have an asp.net chckebox list:

```
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="GradeLevelEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="name=NewCourseRequestDataEntities" 
            DefaultContainerName="NewCourseRequestDataEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
            EntitySetName="grade_levels" OrderBy="it.grade_level_index">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="GradeLevelCheckBoxList" runat="server" cssClass="horizontalcontrols"
            DataSourceID="GradeLevelEntityDataSource" 
            DataTextField="grade_level_description" DataValueField="grade_level_id" AutoPostBack="True"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="CollegeInstitutionsListboxChange"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

A user can return to the page, it gets the record ID, pulls the record data, and should check the appropriate checkboxes:

```
        CheckBoxList grades = (CheckBoxList)FindControl("GradeLevelCheckBoxList");
        foreach (request_grade_college r in CurrentRequest.request_grade_college)
            {
                ListItem grade = grades.Items.FindByValue(r.grade_level_id.ToString());
                    if (grade != null)
                      {
                          grade.Selected = true;
                      }
            }
```

the portion of the code r.grade_level_id.ToString() does return the correct GUID, as type String. However, ListItem grade remain null, so none of the GradeLevelCheckboxList get checked.
What am I missing please?

Comment: can you show us the code where you are binding it?

Comment: @user in which event you have placed the foreach loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the data is not yet bound when you try to access it using Items.FindByValue(), try calling

```
grades.DataBind();
```

before the foreach loop.

Comment: The grades.DataBind() is the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the `listbox` item's `Value` property has the correct value, if Item's `Text` and `Value` are different.

Also, `Value` Property and `grade_level_id` are exactly of same case and with trimmed spaces.